# what is fee_estimates.dat data format?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, raw-data

I'm trying to parse the file fee_estimates.dat.
What is the format of the binary data inside fee_estimates.dat ?
I didn't find any information about it in the dev documentation of Bitcoin.

This is the result of the hexdump command for the first 10 lines :

```
0000000 498c 0002 bf84 0002 bf6d 0007 0000 0000
0000010 0000 0000 00be 0000 0000 8f40 0040 0000
0000020 0000 9068 0040 0000 0000 913a 0040 0000
0000030 8000 9216 6740 6666 0666 92fe 2040 eb85
0000040 2051 93f1 2f40 9db2 61ef 94f0 7e40 3261
0000050 66d5 95fc c540 db4c d25f 9715 0240 d977
0000060 5017 983d f640 0abc 9419 9973 cf40 b1ac
0000070 5b80 9ab9 0d40 ba8f 6ce0 9c0f 0140 c3e3
0000080 98b8 9d76 c140 3414 b9f5 9eef 4c40 54f1
0000090 db3a a03d c340 0c63 bfca a10d c040 f368
```

I tried to read the code of the file fees.cpp but I'm not an C++ expert.

This is my python script :

```
# version required to estimate fees
version_r = f.read(4)
# actual version of my node
version_c = f.read(4)
# best block parsed ??
nFileBestSeenHeight = f.read(4)
# first block with historical fees data ??
nFileHistoricalFirst = f.read(4)
# best block with historical fees data ??
nFileHistoricalBest = f.read(4)
```

After parsing (little endian and bitcoin version decoding) I get :

```
version required: 0.14.99.00
version client: 0.18.01.00
nFileBestSeenHeight: 507757
nFileHistoricalFirst: 0
nFileHistoricalBest: 0
```

I have tried to parse the next bytes without sucess.
Any ideas ?